# CodeIgniter - .htaccess file in captcha folder gets deleted

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, captcha

I have CodeIgniter installed on WAMP in the root directory. The problem comes in here: I've been trying out the captcha's. My captcha folder is `C:\wamp\www\captcha`. The problem is the .htaccess file inside the captcha gets deleted when a new captcha is generated

The content of the .htacces file is:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule !.*\.jpg - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

I use it to return a `Forbidden .....` message if the .... .jpg file exists.

At the moment I only have this in the /view file. I haven't yet implemented any check/submit method. I feel I need to overcome this first.

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
$vals = array(
    'img_path' => './captcha/',
    'img_url' => 'http://localhost/captcha/',
    'img_width' => '150',
    'img_height' => 30,
    'expiration' => 25
    );

$cap = create_captcha($vals);
echo $cap['image'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is quite simple acctually: just create a folder inside `captcha` (in my case `images`), and edit the files accordingly:

**.htaccess** (in `captcha` folder)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.jpg$ ./images/$1\.$2.jpg [L]

RewriteRule !.*\.jpg - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
```

**other "view" file**

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
$vals = array(
    'img_path' => './captcha/images/',
    'img_url' => './captcha/',
    'img_width' => '150',
    'img_height' => 30,
    'expiration' => 3600
    );

$cap = create_captcha($vals);
echo $cap['image'];
```